# How do I get a larger address space for my form?

Tags: html, forms

I have a couple of images below. The top is what I am supposed to create, the bottom is what I currently have. How do I get my address line to look like that? Here is my current code for it:

```html
         <label for="addBox">Address *</label>
         <input type="text" id="addBox" name="address" required>
         <br>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<textarea>` element instead of an `<input>` element

```html
<label for="addBox">Address *</label>
<textarea id="addBox" name="address" required></textarea>
<br>
```